Can MuPDF convert PDF to PDF/A, add bookmarks and convert PDF version 1.3 to 1.7 and vice versa
I am looking the information related to MuPDF. I am trying the mutool on Windows with some functionalities related to PDF like converting PDF to PDF/A, adding bookmarks and converting PDF versions. But unfortunately I have not found any thing related to them.
I would like to know if MuPDF can supply such functionalities?
Thank you.
I am testing with mutool only but I will use MuPDF for my C++ project on Windows.

MuPDF does not (currently at least) produce PDF/A output. I'm not aware of any capability to alter the version of a PDF (because that can potentially mean changing the contents). Outlines (what you describe as bookmarks) can be added I believe. Note that MuPDF has the same license as Ghostscript.
